# Jquery append form in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, append

When using this code in jquery:

```
$('#slider').prepend('<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="dropzone">');
```

Firefox is automatically inserting a form close tag: *(The code below is the resulting HTML)*

```
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
</form>
```

I would like to decide via jquery where to put the form close tag.
Firefox simply ignores my code and inserts the form close tag as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting DOM nodes from javascript is not like writing lines of HTML in source file. Whatever syntax is used, a whole node (a `<form/>` node in your case) is inserted, there's no such thing as half a node. It's all or nothing.

```
$("#slider").prepend("<form>");
//should be written as
$("#slider").prepend("<form/>");
//and, in all browsers, is equivelent to
$("#slider").prepend("<form></form>");
```

If you want your inserted node to have some contents, then either :

```
$("#slider").prepend("<form ...> <!-- all the form's contents here --> </form>")
```

or

```
var $form = $("#slider").prepend("<form ... />");
$form.append(...);
$form.append(...);
$form.append(...);
```

or

```
var $form = $("#slider").prepend("<form ... />");
$form.html(...);
```

or some hybrid of these.